# Copy a part of NSData byte array to another NSData type

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

I have an original `NSData` type which contains let's say 100 bytes. I want to get 2 other `NSData` types. The first containing the first 20 bytes of the 100, and the second one containing the other 80.
They should be copied from the original `NSData`. Sorry if I wasn't so clear, but I'm pretty new with Objective-C.

Comment: use `NSData`'s `-(NSData *)subdataWithRange:(NSRange)range;`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use `NSData`'s `-(NSData *)subdataWithRange:(NSRange)range;` to do that.
From your example, here is some code :

```
// original data in myData
NSData *d1 = [myData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 20)];
NSData *d2 = [myData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(20, 80)];
```

Of course, the ranges are immediate here, you will probably have to do calculations, to make it work for your actual code.

Comment: Thanks Vince, you're so useful to me !

Answer (score 3):

```
 NSData *mainData = /*This is you actual Data*/

 NSData *fPart = [mainData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 20)];
 NSData *sPart = [mainData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(20, 80)];
```

Instead 80 you can use some dynamic - like data length

Comment: Why wouldn't it get 20-79?  Are you sure?

Comment: @AlBeebe No worries... I'm sure I've done the same thing more than once, and the fact that you noticed means that it's time to clean up obsolete comments anyway. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

```
let subdata1 = data?.subdata(in: 0..<20)
let subdata2 = data?.subdata(in: 20..<80)
```

Due to this is question is in very top of Google Search I wanna write here an example for swift